# Indy FTP Failing to upload miserably

Tags: delphi, ftp, indy

Using a simple code, such as:

```
  procedure TForm1.cxButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin
  ftp.Host := 'domain';
  ftp.Username := 'user';
  ftp.Password := 'password';
  ftp.Connect;
  ftp.Put('C:\_Projects\testpicture.JPG');
  ftp.Quit;
  ftp.Disconnect;
  end;
```

I'm getting the following results:

- Application freezes while uploading (ergo unable to see Progress Bar position).
- Uploaded file goes corrupted (corrupts anything more than a few bytes).

What on earth am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Put has 2 parameters from what i know one is the source file and another is the destination file.

Comment: Draft (if Delphi version is modern enough to support OTL) at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788262  Also AsyncCalls lib might be used for elder Delphi versions

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The app freezes because Indy uses blocking operations.  While the code is running, the main message loop is not running, so new messages are not being processed until `cxButton1Click()` exits.  To solve that, either place a `TIdAntiFreeze` component onto your `TForm`, or else move the `TIdFTP` code to a separate worker thread, and then use `TIdSync` or `TIdNotify` to update the UI safely when needed.

The file will be "corrupted" if you are transferring it in ASCII mode instead of in binary mode.  Make sure the `TIdFTP.TransferType` property is set to `ftBinary`.  Indy 9 and earlier defaulted to `ftBinary`, but Indy 10 defaults to `ftASCII` instead (to match the FTP protocol specs).

Comment: Well done. Setting it as a thread and changing to binary worked like a charm. Take this deserving point, thank you.