# delphi Form with multi instance use

Tags: delphi, ftp, indy

i've an FTP uploader project that uses a form created on run time to start uploading to multiple FTP Servers ( using Indy ) , my issue is as follows ( and i really need your help ) .

On a Form i put an IdFTP Component + an Upload button + public properties named FTPSrvAdrs and SrcFile + TrgFolder like this way :

```
type
  TFtpUploader = class(TForm)
    IdFTP: TIdFTP;
    StartUpload:TButton;
    UploadProgress:TProgressBar;
    procedure StartUploadClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  private
    FFtpSrvAdrs:String;
    FSrcFile:String;
    FTargetFtpFld:String;
    Procedure StartMyUpload();
    procedure SetFtpAdrs(const value:string);
    procedure SetSrcFile(const value:string);
    procedure SetTargetFtpFld(const value:string);
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    property FtpAdrs:string read FFtpSrvAdrs write SetFtpAdrs;
    property SourceFile:string read FSrcFile write SetSrcFile;
    property TargetFtpFld:string read FTargetFtpFld write SetTargetFtpFld;
  end;

var
  FtpUploader: TFtpUploader;

implementation

  procedure TFtpUploader.StartUploadClick(Sender: TObject);
  begin
  StartMyUpload(); 
  end;

  procedure TFtpUploader.SetFtpAdrs(const value: string);
  begin
  FFtpSrvAdrs:=value;
  end;

  procedure TFtpUploader.SetSrcFile(const value: string);
   begin
   FSrcFile:=value;
  end;

  procedure TFtpUploader.SetTargetFtpFld(const value: string);
   begin
  FTargetFtpFld:=value;
   end;

   procedure TFtpUploader.StartMyUpload;
    var
    FtpUpStream: TFileStream;
    begin
      ftpUpStream:= TFileStream.create(FSrcFile, fmopenread)
     try
     with IdFTP do begin
      Host:= FFtpSrvAdrs;
      Username:='MyUserName';
      Password:='MyPassword';
    end;
    IdFTP.Connect(true, 1200)
    IdFTP.Passive:= true;
    IdFTP.ChangeDir(FTargetFtpFld)
    IdFTP.Put(ftpUpStream,FSrcFile, false);
   finally
   ftpUpStream.Free;
   end;
   end;


  procedure TFtpUploader.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  begin
  Action:=caFree;
  end;
```

This Form will be created on RunTime ( 4 times = 4 buttons will launch it separately like this way :

in the main form i've this procedure :

```
    Procedure MainForm.UploadTo(FTPSrv,SrcFile,FtpTargetFld:String);
        var
         FUploadFrm:TFtpUploader;
         begin
          FUploadFrm:=TFtpUploader.Create(nil);
          if assigned(FUploadFrm) then
         begin
          FUploadFrm.FtpAdrs:=FTPSrv;
          FUploadFrm.SourceFile:=SrcFile;
          FUploadFrm.TargetFtpFld:=FtpTargetFld;
          FUploadFrm.Show;
         end;
         end;

        procedure MainForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
         begin
        UploadTo('MyFtpSrv_1','MySrcFile_1','MyFtpTargetFld_1');
        end;

         procedure MainForm.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
         begin
         UploadTo('MyFtpSrv_2','MySrcFile_2','MyFtpTargetFld_2');
         end;

// same with other 2 buttons
```

the FtpUploader form is Created / Opened ( 4 instances ) ,The ISSUE IS when i click on StartUpload button the FTP upload process is not started on all these 4 instances , but i've to wait each upload process is done ( finished ) and the other will auto-start , that means not all upload processes are started in same time .

Thank you .

Comment: You did not show ANY of `TFtpUploader` code and how can we guess it ?
*Also you create those instances, but where do you free them ? You can for example at least do TFtpUploader.Create(Application)*

Comment: For example there is no event handler for StartButton click - so it should not react to anything.

Comment: hello they're freed on Close event like this way :
`code`
procedure FtpUploader.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  begin
  Action:=caFree;
  end;
`code`

Comment: Hello. There is no `FtpUploader.FormClose` in your published sources. When you conceal information - you reduce everyone's ability to helpe you. http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: i've just show the minimal code , but if you want i can show it.
I just thought you experts know the mechanism i mean the Code flow

Comment: Sorry for that i will update my code .

Comment: the code flow is arranged by the developer. You "minimized" to the extent that there is no code flow at all. Nothing to react for start button for example. Etc.

Comment: really sorry because i'm new here i've updated the above thread please just if you need more i will give it .

many thanks

Comment: "// here the Upload process should start " hmmm... and still you don't  show the code that actually executes or should be executed...

Well, i'm off. I can only guess, that INDY components are blocking. That your "// here the Upload process should start " does not return until upload completes. And thus the next "// here the Upload process should start " does not start. If your code flow is inside "upload" then it is there and not starting upload once again.
If this random guess is true, you have two options.

Comment: 1) get async event-based or completion port based  TCP components (if they exist at all for Delphi)
2) make your program multi-threading, spawning uploading process into auxillary threads and disabling the forms until download complete. Google for AsyncCalls and try http://otl.17slon.com Hope that would give you useful hints, but i'm tired of asking you for every line there

Comment: I'm really sorry , i've updated the thread along with the TFtpUploader Code .
Sorry again

Comment: routines like `TFtpUploader.SetFtpAdrs` can be replaced by simple `property FtpAdrs:string read FFtpSrvAdrs write FFtpAdrs;`

Comment: If i launch all the 4 instances and click on each StartUpload button on each form the Upload process is not started on all the 4 instances but i must wait till the 1st process is finished then it will go to the next and so on .

But what i want is when i click on each StartUpload button each upload process must start .

Comment: @arioch-the : many thanks but i use it like so because i will extend it latter for some extra Checks .

Comment: But overall you'd have to offload IfFTP.Put into auxillary thread or find some another FTP library. Google Translate may help u read the thread http://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showtopic=324278&view=showall

Comment: Look here, [`Indy FTP Failing to upload miserably`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8318438/576719). Basically you need to move the upload to threads and update the GUI with indy's `TIdSync` and `TIdNotify`.

Comment: OK if i use the idFtp in a separate Thread , will all the 4 FtpUploader form instances start simultaneously ?

Comment: @LURD greate link, the transfer mode is important for FTP and missed here! Is it question effectively a duplicate ?

Comment: @user2240395, No, your 4 uploader forms starts their own upload thread. Your forms will be running the tasks in the background, and properly used the threads will inform the GUI of progress.

Comment: @user2240395 Upload starts when Delphi receives "button pressed" event. In 1 thread case it would not receive it until one file would be uploaded and `IdFTP.Put` returns.

Comment: @Arioch'The, probably a duplicate. The linked answer says everything to solve the problem.

Comment: @LURD i wonder how smart is IdAntiFreeze. Putting it onto form would probably allow user to actually click all 4 buttons while upload in progress... and then unpredicted behavior or what ? A real mine field :-) I wonder if at least one IdFTP would be transferring normally like that....

Comment: @Arioch'The, I would avoid anything with IdAntiFreeze. Bad design. Better to opt for a threaded solution.

Comment: @LURD i agree, anything with ProcessMessages sounds fishy, but there is so much google references to it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have to either change Indy library for some non-blocking in-background library (event based or completion port based), or to make your program multi-threading (with it's own bunch of problems like user clicking a button 20 times or closing the form while the process is going, or even closing the program on the run).

Based on http://otl.17slon.com/book/doku.php?id=book:highlevel:async it can look anything like this:

```
  TFtpUploader = class(TForm)
  private
    CanCloseNow: boolean;

...

  procedure TFtpUploader.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  begin
    if Self.CanCloseNow
       then Action := caFree
       else Action := caIgnore;
  end;

  procedure TFtpUploader.MyUploadComplete;
  begin
    Self.CanCloseNow := True;
    Self.Close;
  end;

  procedure TFtpUploader.StartMyUpload;
  begin
    Self.CanCloseNow := false;
    Self.Enabled := False;
    Self.Visible := True;
    Application.ProcessMessages;

Parallel.Async(
  procedure
    var
    FtpUpStream: TFileStream;
    begin
     ftpUpStream:= TFileStream.create(FSrcFile, fmopenread)
     try
      with IdFTP do begin
       Host:= FFtpSrvAdrs;
       Username:='MyUserName';
       Password:='MyPassword';
       Connect(true, 1200)
       Passive:= true;
       ChangeDir(FTargetFtpFld)

       // this does not return until uploaded
       // thus would not give Delphi a chance to process buttons 
       //    pressed on other forms.
       Put(ftpUpStream,FSrcFile, false);
     end; 
    finally
      ftpUpStream.Free;
    end;
   end
,
  Parallel.TaskConfig.OnTerminated(
    procedure (const task: IOmniTaskControl)
    begin
      MyUploadComplete;
    end;
);
end;
```

Or you can use simplier AsyncCalls library http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/bugfix-units/asynccalls-29-asynchronous-function-calls/